# How can I continue training a neural net in R?

Tags: neural-networks

I have data set that is up-dated every month. I've already trained a neural network on a development sample and validated it. For the building process I used R's nnet package. I also tried  neuralnet.

I am happy with the model. However every month I will get an up-dated dataset.

How can I continue to train the existing network using either of those packages?

Thank you very much in advance,

N

Answer (score 2):

You can use argument "startweights" - assumed that your actual network is "NNetwork", code should look like

```
NNetwork <- neuralnet(formula, data, startweights = NNetwork$weights)
```